# What happens after I enter the command node app.js while building a web application with express

Tags: node.js, express

I am an intermediate level developer on MEAN Stack, but I wanted to understand this, as to what exactly happens after I press run node app.js. After reading a lot, this is what I found out. Correct me if I am wrong.

Step 1 : All of the JavaScript code written is complied and looked for syntactic errors. If that is error free, the node starts to listen on the mentioned port. By listening I mean in layman languages is, it kinda opens a door where anything could come from that door.

Step 2: All the routes are listed somewhere like these are GET, these are POST request etc. A guard on that door will check the incoming request, and see if it matches any of the routes. If the HTTP header and routes and permissions(CORS) are matched, the guard gives it permission to go and execute that particular route, and then the response is sent back through the same door, with the required fields like status, data etc.

Mid-Step: When the request is being processed, all the IO tasks are given to underlying threads by libev and when they complete, they come back to the event table and then are processed by the event loop.

**Is this understanding correct? Would somebody like to add something to it. Probably something that I am missing.**

**EDIT**

```
/*Writing var once and declaring all dependencies at once is considered a
good practice.*/
var express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var  io = require('socket.io')(server);
/*All my confidential data, keys go in here*/
require('./config/credentials.js').db(app, mongoose);
require('./config/environment.js')(app, express, bodyParser, cookieParser, session, passport, mongoose);

/*Models*/
Users = require('./models/users.js');

var checkauth = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("In checkauth");
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("In isAuthenticated");
        next();
    } else {
        console.log("Doesn't authenticate");
        res.status(401);
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            'success': false
        }));
    }
};
/*Routes to all my files*/

require('./routes/index.js')(app, express, io);
require('./routes/vehico.js')(app);

/*Mobile Routes.*/
require('./routes/mobile/auth.js')(app, passport, mongoose);
require('./routes/mobile/settings.js')(app, checkauth);
require('./routes/mobile/cars.js')(app, checkauth);
require('./routes/mobile/devices.js')(app, checkauth);
require('./routes/mobile/locations.js')(app, checkauth);
require('./routes/mobile/group.js')(app, checkauth);
require('./routes/mobile/analytics.js')(app, checkauth);

/* Device Route */
require('./routes/device.js')(app, io);
require('./routes/trip.js')(app, checkauth);
require('./routes/mobile.js')(app, express, checkauth);
app.listen(app.get('port')); // port should be in config folder in a file not out here in open.
console.log('Express server listening on port 4000');
```

Comment: Your question isn't about nodejs, but about expressjs. Nodejs has no "routes". It's not an http server.

Comment: First off, node is a general purpose engine that runs Javascript.  What you are describing is a very specific type of application that creates a web server.  Apparently (we're just guessing since you didn't show us any of your code), your app.js file actually creates and starts a web server, but that is not built into node - you're specific app has to do that.  You would likely get much more meaningful answers if you showed us your app.js file.

Comment: As your question stands now it's extremely broad.  It sounds like you're asking to describe how a node.js-based web server with express routes works.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added the code. I am not asking anyone to explain, I am asking, is my understanding correct? Is there more than what I know. I want to learn better not by code but by understanding how something works. The code comes later for me.

Comment: Your explanation is pretty simplistic and not very detailed and the only way to say anything beyond "no it's not entirely correct" involves a very broad explanation of how things actually work.

Comment: Okay, so there are two things from here, either somebody can provide a detailed answer to it. Or you can point to a specific resource which mentions the steps. If there is no resource which exists which answers the question, wouldn't it help the community to have a specific detailed answer. Tell me If I am wrong and I shall delete the question.

Comment: This is what makes your question incredibly broad.  In your question, you've covered "How does starting node.js work?", "How does a web server in node.js work?", "How do routes in node.js and express work?, "How does your auth model you are using work?", etc...  It's just way too broad for this site.  This site works well when you pick one area and ask a specific question about that.  Honestly, it could take an entire book to really cover everything you've touched on.  It's not that an answer wouldn't be useful, it's just way too much for a question on this site.

Comment: @jfriend00 just asking how to get this answered, Is there a book I could read. or should I be asking 4 different question. I really wanted this answered and I cannot find resources or screencast which cover all these questions, even differently. All resources focus on how does nodeJS exploits asynchronous IO to work faster than traditional thread-process based IO, on which I have a hold.